# PHP Session variables are lost after moving to a page

Tags: php, ajax, session

I'm having a lot of trouble losing session variables in PHP. I've found a lot of good information but nothing that helps me in this case. Here are my PHP files:

First, util.php. It's included at the top of every file. It has the session_start() command and the MySQL connect string:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","mysql","mypassword","mydb");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Failed to connect to database ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

Next, show_variables.php. It dumps all the session variables on screen:

```
<?php
echo date('H:i:s');
echo "<br/><p>Session Variables:</p>";
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
    echo $key." ".$val."<br/>";
echo session_name();
?>
```

Now the first page, index.php. The top of the page pulls employee names from a database table. The body presents a form with the employee names and two roles. The page redirects based on which role is selected.

```
<?php
    include "util.php";
    $query=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from staff");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $staff_select .= '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[name_first].' '.$row[name_last].'</option>';
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Restaurant Order Tracking</title>
    <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function start_shift(){
            var e_select = document.selector.employee_select;
            var name = e_select.options[e_select.selectedIndex].value;
            var r_select = document.selector.role_select;
            var role = r_select.options[r_select.selectedIndex].value;
            alert("Ok, " + name + ". You're a " + role + " today. Let's get to work.");
            if(role == "server"){location = "./server/server.php?id=" + name};
            if(role == "foodprep"){location = "foodprep.php?id=" + name};
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Welcome To The Restaurant Order Tracker</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
        <p>Now get to work !</p>
        <form name="selector">
            <p>Select your employee:</p>
            <select name="employee_select">
                <?php
                  echo $staff_select;
                ?>
            </select>
            <p>Select your role for today</p>
            <select name="role_select">
                <option value="server">Server</option>
                <option value="foodprep">Food Prep</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <input type="button" value="Start Shift" onclick="start_shift()"/>
        </form>
    <?php include "show_variables.php";?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This page works fine. Selecting server here leads to "server.php". Here's that file:

```
<?php
    include "../util.php";
    $_SESSION['id']=$id=$_GET['id'];
    $_SESSION['foo']="fubar";
    $query = mysqli_query($connect,"select name_first, name_last from staff where id = $id");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name_first'].' '.$row['name_last'];
        }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <Title>Server Interface</Title>
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function update(target){
            var ajaxRequest;
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                    var middleDisplay = document.getElementById('middle');
                    middleDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                    }
                }
            ajaxRequest.open("GET", target, true);
            ajaxRequest.send(null);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <p>Server Interface</p>
        <p>Server Name: <?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?>  </p>
        <form action="../logout.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
        <?php include "stage1.php" ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This pages sets three variables: id, name, and foo. As expected, the show_variable.php has the following output:

```
19:54:34
Session Variables:
id 2
foo fubar
name Dave Smith
PHPSESSID
```

There's also an include for stage1.php in the middle div. Here's that file:

```
<br/>
<form name="selector">
    <input type="button" value="Start a new order" name="new_order" onclick = "update('new_order.php')" />
    <input type="button" value="View your open orders" name="view_order" onclick="update('view_order.php')" />
</form>
<?php include "../show_variables.php"; ?>
```

So far, so good. There's some AJAX to change the middle div, and that works great. If the user selects "start new order," AJAX puts new_order.php in the middle div. Here's that file:

```
<?php
    include "../util.php";
    $query=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from loc");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $table_select .= '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[description].'</option>';
    }
    echo "<br/>
    <form name = 'new_order'>
    <label>Enter the table number for this order</label>
        <select name = 'table_select'>
            $table_select
        </select>
        <br/>
        <input type='button' value='Start New Order' onclick=\"update('enter_order.php?table=' + document.new_order.table_select[document.new_order.table_select.selectedIndex].value)\" />
        <br/>
        <input type='button' value='Cancel New Order' onclick=\"update('stage1.php')\" />
    </form>
<a href= "stage1.php">Go back to stage 1 via link</a>
"
?>
<?php include "../show_variables.php"; ?>
```

This page also shows the correct session variables:

```
19:55:27
Session Variables:
id 2
foo fubar
name Dave Smith
PHPSESSID
```

But after that, all the variables disappear. If the user clicks on "Cancel New Order", the AJAX script fills the middle div with stage1.php again. And the session variables are no longer present:

```
19:59:12
Session Variables:
PHPSESSID
```

This can't be a typo in the stage1.php file. The exact same code has the session variables in one viewing, but loses them in another. 
I thought maybe AJAX was screwing me up, so I added the href to new_order.php. That went straight to stage1.php without any AJAX/JavaScript. But the variables were, once again, lost.

I tried entering URLs manually.
I browse to http://www.mysite.com/server/server.php?id=1. Session variables appear correctly.
I open a new tab and browse to http://www.mysite.com/server/server.php (no get's). Session variables are present and set the same.
I open another tab and browse to http://www.mysite.com/server/stage1.php. Session variables are not present.

Note that every file has the session_start() command via the util.php file. Note also that this is a development server. Mine is the only session on the site. Any ideas?

Comment: Checkout some of the comments in the documentation for session_start(). Sounds like you fit one of the entries there: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from the code you posted, but it appears to me that stage1.php doesn't call util.php which calls session_start.

So stage1.php appears to have no session_start

To avoid double includes, you could use include_once

Comment: Ah, that was it. The first time around stage1.php was just included (pasted) in server.php, and thus it was just part of server.php. But when the AJAX script explicitly calls stage1.php, it behaves as if it were an independent file. Thus the "include util.php" command that's in server.php isn't executed. Thanks. More than just finding a typo, you've helped me understand PHP's logic a little better.